# Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'trace' of undefined to start

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I had an project in beta version and I have update my project to latest version.

> Here is my **ionic** info

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v7.2.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'trace' of undefined to start
>   watch failed:a watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start.it likely that to file

check this full [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5TgT.png)